# Putting comma in infinitive

Tags: infinitive, comma

I don't know exactly when to put commas in sentences with *infinitive*. For example, I saw two sentences:

> Mein Bruder schien im siebten Himmel zu sein.
>
> Er hatte sogar vergessen, mir Geld zu schicken.

Why is the second sentence divided into parts by a comma whereas the first sentence isn't?

Comment: I don't believe the comma in the srcond sentence is necessary, where exactly did you get that from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was reading a book with German stories

Comment: Could well be a simple typo. I am not aware of such grammar rule.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would say the latter sentence looks like a "erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu" that should get a comma in old orthography.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma in the second sentence was mandatory in the old orthography before 1996 but is optional in the current orthography. It introduces an infinitive clause. See Duden D114-117.

The same would apply to the first sentence if it was not for the verb *scheinen* which is never used with comma (Duden D117).

For further reference, see [here](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma).